# Creating a new excel file in a document librabry creates a second empty file SPO

Tags: document-library, excel, template, online

On Sharepoint Online, I have a document library with a custom content type on which I have an excel template file.
When I create a new file in the browser, Sharepoint asked to modify a copy and to name it. I can modify it and it is automatically saved.

When I go back to the library, it created the file I wanted, say MyExcel.xlsx, but it also created an empty excel file based on my template, named Classeur.xlsx (its french for spreadsheet, since my SPO is in French).

I have tested with a new document library, using the content type Documents and a different excel file as template. The result is the same.

How come that this empty file is created ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the custom content type as the default content type for the library.